# Qt retrieve QFlags form QVariant

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

Here is a code exemple:

```
#include <QDebug>

enum Pouet
{
    F1 = 1,
    F2 = 2,
    F3 = 4,
};
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Pouets, Pouet)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pouets)
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(Pouets)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Pouets p = F1|F3;
    qDebug()<<p;
    qDebug()<<QVariant(p).toString();
    qDebug()<<QVariant(QVariant(p).toString()).value<Pouets>();

}
```

Output:

```
QFlags(0x1|0x4)
"5"
QFlags()
```

Please, what is wrong here?
I simply can't retrieve a QFlag previously stored in a QVariant?

Comment: try with this: `enum Pouet
{
    F1 = 1,
    F2 = 2,
    F3 = 4,
};
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Pouets, Pouet)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pouet)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Pouets)
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(Pouets)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Pouets p = F1|F3;
    qDebug()<<p;
    qDebug()<<QVariant(p).toString();
    Pouets ps = QVariant(p).value<Pouet>();
    qDebug()<< ps;
}
`

Comment: Yes it works! Thx

Comment: If I post my answer you would mark it as correct. :P